# How to Encrypt URL parameters if using Method GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, session-variables

I need help about Encryption for URL parameters using Method GET (pages)

this code a default session (index.php)

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {     
    header ('location: login.php');//i try redirect to our pages with 
    encryption method get
}
```

and the URL (`login.php`) will encryption automatically (`md5` or anymore) if we opened the URL.

how to solved? using `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 2):

`GET` requests can be encrypted if the HTTP connection is made using SSL or TLS... though they'll still be able to be read by browser plugins and server logs. You'd be far better off using `POST` requests if you want to encrypt your requests, as these do not leak information in any way.

However, in your particular instance, you're simply trying to 'mask' the url `login.php`. This isn't strictly necessary -- anyone on the page will **know** it's a login page without needing to read the URL). However, if you really want to obscure the name, you can simply rename the `.php` file itself to something random.

Also note that MD5 is **[insecure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)**; use a more secure algorithm instead.

Answer (score 0):

You canot encript data with .htacess. To encrypt url parametrs use any encryption algorithams before passing data